# DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in PRO Prepaid Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm using PDO to handle (MYSQL)Database.When i save the result this SQL didn't update the column values it will create a new line with new saving values.What is the mistake i done.Is there anyone can help me to understand this behavior with PDO

```
$SQL =<<<'EOD'
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pard_admin_config(
title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
online varchar(100),
offline varchar(100),
email varchar(100),
metades varchar(200),
metakey varchar(200),
copyright varchar(200),
pard_host varchar(100),
pard_database varchar(100),
username varchar(100),
password varchar(100)
)
EOD;

$pardConfig->query($SQL);


$stmt = $pardConfig->prepare("INSERT INTO pard_admin_config (title, online, offline, email, metades, metakey, copyright, pard_host, pard_database, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
title='?', online='?', offline='?', email='?', metades='?', metakey='?', copyright='?', pard_host='?', pard_database='?', username='?', password='?'");

$ConfigData = array($adminConfig->TITLE,
 $adminConfig->ONLINE,
 $adminConfig->OFFLINE,
 $adminConfig->EMAIL,
 $adminConfig->METADESCRIPTION,
 $adminConfig->METAKEYWORDS,
 $adminConfig->COPYRIGHT,
 $adminConfig->HOST,
 $adminConfig->DATABASE,
 $adminConfig->USERNAME,
 $adminConfig->PASSWORD);
$stmt->execute($ConfigData);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not PDO behavior, but mysql

You need to specify either the same values twice, or use values() function

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
title= values(title), online=values(online), and so on
```

also note that placing placeholders in quotes makes no sense.

Comment: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
title=values(title), online=values(online), offline=values(offline), email=values(email), metades=values(metades), metakey=values(metakey), copyright=values(copyright), pard_host=values(pard_host), pard_database=values(pard_database), username=values(username), password=values(password)");

Comment: It means create another raw with saving values